# I need a solution for a menu that "breaks" too soon

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, line-breaks

Menu width is set to 80% and centered. What I would like to happen is for the menu to be as responsive as other page elements, i.e. adjust it's size/width until the screen is a specific size (say 1200px or so), then split in half. When the screen width hits 910px or below, the menu collapses into a `hamburger`. That works correctly. What doesn't work correctly is that the slightest adjustment in screen size causes one or more of the "li" items to drop down a row. Is there a way to force the "li" menu to split in half (after the 4th item) at a certain screen size? I have tried many different combinations of `ul li:nth-child(4) a` commands, but nothing seems to have any effect.

Comment: You can see the site I'm working on here: http://www.kimswebpages.com/dentist2/drvt

Answer (score 0):

On the appropriate screensize, set the .nav li `width: 25%` and `float: left`. Make your .nav a `display:block`

Make sure you clear the floats with a `clear:both` element, or a clearfix on the container.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want the buttons to always be in equal rows?

A simple approach for just a single split would be to put the buttons in to two divs with display:inline set, and use nonbreaking spaces to separate the buttons. That way, there is no breakpoint within the div so insufficient width should force the whole second div onto a new line.

Or, I could suggest splitting the buttons into two divs with default display:inline css, and if a split is needed on the basis of viewport width, then change the display property of one to block with js. That will force the rest onto a new line. Not tried it but in principle it should work.

As an interesting alternative, you can it seems separate the items with br tags which have display:none set. In which case they do nothing. Changing that to display:block activates the br, forcing a newline. I'm not sure if this is approved css but it works in FF and Chrome.

Scary subject, BTW. Had me cowering under the desk. ;)